# Buildozer can't compile Cython

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy, archlinux

I am trying to build my kivy application, but having run `buildozer android debug --verbose` the only I get is following:

```
[...]

Run prebuild
Call prebuild_hostpython
Call prebuild_python
Call prebuild_sdl
Call prebuild_pygame
Call prebuild_pyjnius
Call prebuild_android
Call prebuild_kivy
Run build
Skipped build_hostpython
Skipped build_python
Skipped build_sdl
Skipped build_pygame
Call build_pyjnius
Entering in ARM environment
Compiler found at /home/michal/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/Labirynt/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build_ext
building 'jnius' extension
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/michal/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -DNDEBUG -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/michal/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -fPIC -I/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/Labirynt/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7 -c jnius/jnius.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/jnius/jnius.o
jnius/jnius.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
 #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
  ^
error: command 'arm-linux-androideabi-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            if py_arg is None:
                j_args[index].l = NULL
            elif isinstance(py_arg, basestring) and \
                    argtype in ('Ljava/lang/String;', 'Ljava/lang/Object;'):
                j_args[index].l = j_env[0].NewStringUTF(
                        j_env, <char *><bytes>py_arg.encode('utf-8'))
                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

jnius/jnius_conversion.pxi:54:31: Casting temporary Python object to non-numeric non-Python type
/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/Labirynt/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build_ext
building 'jnius' extension
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/michal/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -DNDEBUG -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/michal/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -fPIC -I/home/michal/Dokumenty/Projekty/Labirynt/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7 -c jnius/jnius.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/jnius/jnius.o
jnius/jnius.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
 #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
  ^
error: command 'arm-linux-androideabi-gcc' failed with exit status 1
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "testapp"
```

I'm using Archlinux, 64bit, python2 2.7.8-2, with aur/python2-kivy-git.

When i'm trying to install aur/python2-kivy I get

```
Found GLES 2.0 headers at /usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h
 /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'dependency_links'
   warnings.warn(msg)
 /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
   warnings.warn(msg)
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Build configuration is:
 * use_rpi = False
 * use_opengl_es2 = True
 * use_opengl_debug = False
 * use_glew = False
 * use_sdl = False
 * use_ios = False
 * use_mesagl = False
 * use_x11 = False
 * use_gstreamer = True
 * use_avfoundation = False
Generate config.h
Generate config.pxi
Detected compiler is unix
skipping 'kivy/graphics/texture.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'kivy/graphics/vertex.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'kivy/graphics/fbo.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'kivy/graphics/context.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'kivy/properties.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'kivy/graphics/context_instructions.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'kivy/graphics/instructions.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'kivy/graphics/stencil_instructions.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'kivy/graphics/opengl.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'kivy/graphics/transformation.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'kivy/graphics/vbo.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'kivy/graphics/opengl_utils.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'kivy/graphics/c_opengl_debug.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'kivy/graphics/gl_instructions.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
cythoning kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx to kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.c

 Error compiling Cython file:
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 ...

             g_object_set_void(self.playbin, 'video-sink', self.fakesink)

         # configure playbin
         g_object_set_int(self.pipeline, 'async-handling', 1)
         c_uri = <bytes>self.uri.encode('utf-8')
                ^
 ------------------------------------------------------------

 kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:259:16: Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference
building 'kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer' extension
gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.o
kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
 #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
  ^
 error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: I have the exact same problem on ubuntu 14.04, and downgrading cython didn't solve it for me

Comment: @fccoelho This question is for Arch, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue with the Cython version 0.21 and old code. The easiest solution is to downgrade Cython to 0.20, which works.

To use the newer Cython, delete the downloaded pyjnius and let buildozer download the most recent version:

```
rm ~/.buildozer/android/packages/pyjnius-master.zip
```

But the newer Cython also needs newer Kivy code. In your buildozer.spec, change `kivy` in the requirements to `kivy==master` to get the most recent Kivy code.